# Keyboard-Shortcut to go to the ONLY call of a method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I know I can Shift-F12 to find references and then click to go to the call location.

But is there a way to go there directly (assuming, of course, that there is indeed only ***one*** location where the method is called from)?

Comment: I don't think so... the references link of code lens might be easier (but i is an aspect of VS that I've yet to get my fingers to use without a mouse). Alt-2 then step down to pick the reference: at least this works anywhere is the method.

Comment: Resharper supports this, with alt-backtick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using these shortcuts

- Go to definition `F12`
- Go to implementation `Ctrl+F12`

Comment: That's for an interface, for where it's _implemented_. Not for a method for where it's called (=used) from.